# Replace . in decimal with ,

Tags: jquery, counter

I have an animated counter that counts up some number. It works good with a decimal and looks like this: `111.90`. But I need to show the number with a comma instead of dot, like this `111,90`. How can I replace the dot but to save the counter effect?
Here is the code:

```
$('.animate-math .number').waypoint({

offset      : '100%',
handler     : function(){

        var el          = $( this.element );
        var duration    = Math.floor( ( Math.random() * 1000 ) + 1000 );
        var to          = el.attr( 'data-to' );

        $({ property:0 }).animate({ property:to }, {
            duration    : duration,
            easing      :'linear',
            step        : function() {
                el.text( Math.floor( this.property ) );
            },
            complete    : function() {
                el.text( this.property );
            }
        });

        if( typeof this.destroy !== 'undefined' && $.isFunction( this.destroy ) ){
            this.destroy();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Easy solution can be `string.replace(".", ",")`

Comment: Of course this is the first solution I have came up with. But where exactly should I place this ``replace`` in my code? Nothing worked out.

Comment: `yourNumber.toString().replace(...)`

Comment: Do I have to ``.replace`` myNumber before the function or after? I don't know how to use the replace in my case.